# Noda Time versus BCL performance metrics comparison

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datetime-format

Have any metrics been done with Noda Time that compare Noda Time and the BCL for equivalent functions?  I am specifically interested in DateTime.ToString (DateTimeFormat) and DateTime.ParseExact.  I found benchmarks for Noda Time but I am wondering about the results for the same test with BCL.

Comment: Search for links/off-site resources is generally off-topic. If you can't measure metrics yourself there is a good chance that performance does not really matter that much for project you work on - pick whatever works correctly for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

NodaTime has BCL and NodaTime benchmarks in its most recent implementation that runs on VisualStudio 2015 (the most recent version uses post VisualStudio 2012 components that caused the donwloaded NodaTime code to not compile out of the box for me on VisualStudio 2012).  The NodaTime BCL and NodaTime benchmark tests indicated NodaTime was about the same as BCL.  In addition, I created a benchmark application that used NodaTime and BCL to format a UTC datetime in a "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ" format and also did not see a significant difference between the two of them.  So NodaTime appears to have accomplished its goal of not being less optimal but it does not look like it is going to gain you a significantly more optimized performance if that is your goal.